# Is there an adjective meaning ambitious and financially successful in contrast to thrifty/frugal?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective meaning ambitious and financially successful, in contrast to thrifty or frugal? Ambitious is close to what I'm looking for: someone who takes risks in order to improve their financial standing, but is likely to succeed.

Someone can succeed financially by being thrifty or frugal, but others spend money and take shrewd risks in order to launch a grand plan and be successful.

Example:

> Arthur and Bertram both became wealthy, but whereas Arthur was thrifty,
> and gained by saving all he could and making careful investments,
> Bertram was ______: somehow, he found the most amazing opportunities,
> and jumped from one to the next. To watch Bertram was to see a rising star
> in action, knowing he would reach far but never over-reaching
> to the point of disaster.

"Ambitious" (and other words like "determined" or "striving") doesn't carry a financial connotation; words like "rich" and "successful" and "prosperous" don't carry the connotation of striving upwards.

"Entrepreneurial" and "competitive" and "aggressive" and "opportunistic" are closer....

Comment: a risk taker or risk taking

Comment: He was shrewd, intuitive, visionary.

Comment: As @YosefBaskin said, *shrewd* was the first word that came to my mind.

Comment: hmm, I could see *shrewd businessman* but by itself *shrewd* doesn't have financial connotations.

Comment: Maybe there just isn't a good single adjective, sigh.

Comment: *Shrewd* suggests something more similar to thrifty to me: wily, hardheaded, keeping track of the pennies, more Warren Buffett than Elon Musk. *Entrepreneurial* seems better.